# Can´t add Bootstrap 4 in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular6

I have the problem when I try to add the latest bootstrap version with

```
npm install bootstrap
```

After that, I got an error message when I tried to run it.

```
ng serve --open
```

I Add Bootstrap in angular.json

like this

```
"styles": [
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
```

And the error message is

```
    ERROR in multi ../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css ./src/styles.css
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '...\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css' in '...'
```

Why did I get the error message?

Comment: did you install jquery?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Delete `"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",` in the Angular.json.

Try add this `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";` to your style.css file.

Ref: [Styling Angular CLI v6 apps with Bootstrap](https://medium.com/@beeman/tutorial-styling-angular-cli-v6-apps-with-bootstrap-8d4f8ea5adae)

Answer (score 3):

If the project has a test runner like Karma the Angular.json file has two styles property:

1- projects -> projectName -> architect -> build -> options

2- projects -> projectName -> architect -> test -> options

[image: Add bootstrap to angular.json]

Maybe you just change styles in the test section and the build section has old styles.

Answer (score 2):

In the **Angular 6** you can add bootstrap to two files:

1. Inside the **angular.json**:

   ```
   "styles": [
       "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
       "src/styles.css"
   ]
   ```
2. Inside the **angular.json**:

   ```
   "styles": [
       "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
       "src/styles.css"
   ]
   ```
3. Inside the **styles.css**:

   ```
   /* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
   @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
   ```

> **Note**: If you use the first or second way, it's needed to cancel the running application, that means, if **ng serve** is active you must exit the app with `Ctrl + C`, but in the third way, it's not needed to cancel the application.

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of angular, use **node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css** instead of **../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css**

So in angular.json file style attribute will look like

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
 ]
```

**NOTE:** if **ng serve** is already running then you may need to stop and run it again after doing the above changes. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

In angular, We have to add the direction of the bootstrap we installed.
Which means steps are as follows to use bootstrap in angular.

```
1. npm install bootstrap
```

Then we have to add the path in angular.json as follows

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

With Angular 16 I had to install bootstrap and also jQuery (rpm install jQuery --save).
Then I added to angular.json this information:

```
        "styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```