# Bootstrap not working in Angular 6 app

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular6

I want to make use of Bootstrap in an Angular 6 app and here is what I have done so far but nothing seems to be working out:

1) Installed bootstrap, jquery and popper.js using npm.
2) Entered the following in the Angular.json file

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
    "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ...
]
```

Am I missing something. This doesn't seems to work out.

Comment: You can fix the problem in the Angular.json file like [fix bootstrap in angular.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806954/7487135)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in your **`style.scss`** files use `import`

```
@import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"
```

and remove `"node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss"` from `angular.json` file

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559810/bootstrap-not-connect-to-the-angular-6/50559906#50559906

Comment: yeh  it's working but when i am trying to open a modal it's not dismissing and taking the whole page.please help me. Thanks

Comment: I recoomand you to post a question... If you post one let me konw the link to question

Comment: ok i will do that and one more thing how to  add Jquery in Angular 6

Comment: Jquery install by default when you install bootstrap here is how to use:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421917/how-to-use-jquery-ui-in-angular-6

Answer (score 5):

First install bootstrap to the App:

```
npm install bootstrap@latest --save (flag is optional)
```

Then import the bootstrap to the index.html file in Angular:

```
@import '~bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css'; (~ means the node_Modules)
```

I hope this answers your question.