# how to use jquery-ui in angular 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jquery-ui, angular6

I have tried number of methods posted on StackOverflow to use **jquery-ui** in **angular 6** component but none of them worked. For example,

1. I ran **npm install jquery jquery-ui** to install jquery and jquery-ui.
2. Included following in angular.json

   "scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
     "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",

**Error is as follows:**

```
AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js [sm]:1ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__(...).slider is not a function
    at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.ngAfterContentInit (http:||localhost:4200/main.js:154:56)
    at callProviderLifecycles (http:||localhost:4200/vendor.js:42663:18)
    at callElementProvidersLifecycles (http:||localhost:4200/vendor.js:42644:13)
    at callLifecycleHooksChildrenFirst (http:||localhost:4200/vendor.js:42634:29)
    at checkAndUpdateView (http:||localhost:4200/vendor.js:43565:5)
    at callWithDebugContext (http:||localhost:4200/vendor.js:44454:25)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (http:||localhost:4200/vendor.js:44132:12)
    at ViewRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewRef_.detectChanges (http:||localhost:4200/vendor.js:41948:22)
    at http:||localhost:4200/vendor.js:37684:63
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Car Dealer</title>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body> 
</html>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div id="slider">
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  title = 'MDK';

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider({
      range: true,
      values: [ 17, 67 ]
    });
  }
}
```

Another post suggested that I **should not use** angular.json of angular 6 at all but use index.html to include scripts but it also did not worked.

I included following in index.html but even then same error appeared

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: import the lib in the `angular.cli.json` under the section `scripts`, you should not use directly jQuery, in this scenario, but the cli.json is fine, everything should be imported there. You can also use ` npm install jquery` and then add int the cli.json the scripts taken from node-modules folder

Comment: In angular.json, I have added following lines already. There is no angular-cli.json in Angular6. 

"scripts": [ 
"node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
 "node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js",
.
.

Comment: Try replacing your import with `declare let $: any;`

Comment: When I replaced, the error disappeared but slider is not appearing. Any clue?

Comment: Thanks David. Seems like I forgot to include following in angular 6 /src/styles.css

@import "../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.min.css"; Now it is working perfectly. Thanks a lot!!!! Could you write what is the difference between import and let as you suggested.

Comment: I tried to explain it in my answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you write

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

then only the code for `jquery` (and not extra plugins, like `jquery-ui`) will be imported by typescript compiler into the `$` variable.

If you use

```
 declare let $: any;
```

Then you are just notifying typescript that this variable exist. In that case, `$` will contain whatever what assigned to it in the scripts you imported in `angular.json`, which is `jquery` AND `jquery-ui` plugins

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It says ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Please update your **scripts** part in **angular.json** file

```
"scripts": [
           "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
           "../node_modules/jquery-ui-dist/jquery-ui.js"
        ]
```