# How to fix issue when including jQuery in Angular project and attempt using Reactive Forms

Tags: jquery, angular, forms, jquery-select2

I have an Angular 7 project in which I want to use the Select2 library.
In order to use Select2, I need to include jQuery as well. To add to all of that, I want to use Angular's Reactive Forms for my form.

Here is a link to a [github example project](https://github.com/MBarjawi/AngularJQueryFormTest) for whoever wishes to see the files.

Here is the problem:
There are two methods to include jQuery in a ts file:

1. `import * as $ from 'jquery';`
2. `declare let $: any`

Using the first method (i.e., using the import statement) to include jQuery, I can't use the select2 library as the jQuery object returned by $ doesn't have the extra libraries added. I got this information from this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421917/how-to-use-jquery-ui-in-angular-6). And so I get the following error:
`select2 is not a function`

Using the second method (i.e., using the declare statement) to include jQuery, the Select2 library works fine, but now the Reactive Forms don't work as expected. Neither the subscription to listen to form changes is called, nor the formData is updated properly. Clicking the submit button and then viewing the form data in the console always shows null in the value object.

So I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I need to use both, Select2 and Reactive Forms but not sure how to do so.

Comment: Do you really need select2? https://ng-select.github.io/ is a good alternative

Comment: That's a good question. The simple answer is no. However, Select2 is an example of the problem. I am using other libraries as well that need the usage of 'declare' method to declare jQuery...

So I guess I have to look for alternative libraries and put time and effort learning them... or I can find a solution to the problem in this question and save learning/updating time.

Comment: Seems nobody found a fix for this issue yet!
It is a shame as there are many good libraries/frameworks/tools/utilities that use the jquery original style... now we wouldn't be able to use them without troubles in latest Angular!

Comment: That's because a lot of em have a ported version or have similar component. Once you choose to use jQuery, you're on your own. You will have to create a wrapper around your jQuery library which inherit `ControlValueAccessor` to work with Reactive Forms. So you can research a bit on that... Other than that I don't think there's any other options if you want to integrate with jQuery with Angular.