# How to use JQueryUI in Angular10?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, angular10

I am working in Angular 10. I am new in Angular. I want to use drag and drop of JQUeryUI in AngularJS 10 but not getting the right solution that how can I use JQueryUI in angular. I am using the Visual Studio Code for development.

I have searched and spent many hours behind it but didn't get any proper solution for it. Almost all references are showing high-level code directly or for the older version.

A few links I have attached here below which I got from finding/searching solution.
http://www.smartjava.org/content/drag-and-drop-angularjs-using-jquery-ui/

https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop

http://logicbomb.github.io/ng-directives/drag-drop.html

[How to use jQuery UI with Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41861464/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-angular-2)

[how to use jquery-ui in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52421917/how-to-use-jquery-ui-in-angular-6)

Please can you guide me that how can I use JQuery-UI in AngularJS 10?